# htaccess - Auth on Laravel excluding public directory

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, cas

I'm currently hosting a site on a Linux server without access to the root system. I am only able to change .htaccess files under my allocated directory.

### Background

Basically, I am required to use `AuthType CAS` in my application. A request to a file protected by this would be redirected to a foreign domain authentication server and then back to the site if the login was successful. **The background of my issue is I needed to deal with CORS when requesting for resources in Chrome.**

- I host on `app.x.com`.
- The authentication server is on `cas.x.com`
- A request of `app.x.com/resource` gets redirected to `cas.x.com/cas/login_service?http%3a%2f%2fapp.x.com%2fresource` then back.

I fail to load fonts of Font Awesome on Chrome for example, because the requested URL is on `cas.x.com` where I have no control on, and it doesn't have the header to allow my domain as an origin. (TBH, I don't understand why browsers are implemented this way, because the CSS loaded fine from my domain, but the fonts loaded from the CSS became requests to the CAS server, but I digress.)

---

So I wanted to only authenticate for the `index.php` file of Laravel. By having the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "index.php">
    AuthType CAS
    CASAuthNHeader On
    Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

But then, the redirection shows an error, and this approach fails because of an incorrect redirection:

- `302  http://app.x.com/internal/marketplace redirects to http://cas.x.com/cas/login_service?http%3a%2f%2fapp.x.com%2fpublic%2findex.php`
- `302   http://cas.x.com/cas/login_service?http%3a%2f%2fapp.x.com%2fpublic%2findex.php redirects to http://app.x.com/public/index.php?ticket=ST-1180135-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-cas2`
- ...
- `404   http://app.x.com/public/index.php`

It shows 404 because I do not have that path routed in Laravel.

Without the `FilesMatch` section, the redirection would look like: `http://cas.x.com/cas/login_service?http%3a%2f%2fapp.x.com%2finternal%2fmarketplace`

**How can I apply Auth to only `index.php` or apply to the entire site but excluding directories and files inside `public/`?**